# Simple password protection for part of R Shiny app using hashing

Tags: r, sqlite, hash, shiny, password-protection

I am writing an R Shiny app that will eventually be online. Part of the app needs password protection. Only people with a correct password can add certain info on the app. Right now my approach is as follows:

1. Hash the entered password from a text box with SHA or a similar hashing algorithm.
2. Compare the hash with a table of hashes in the database with permission to use part of the app.
3. Only send the input information to the database if the password is acceptable.

My question is whether this approach has security flaws? Is there a better way to do this?

I am not terribly familiar with what people can access regarding the code or databases used to create shiny apps when they are online, which is why I was not sure if this was a good method.

Thanks!

Comment: can't you host the site on an already secure enviroment, like a company vpn or the rstudio cloud, or shinnyapps.io?

Comment: @Bruno Yes I could. Would that eliminate the need for hashing because the table containing password information would be inaccessible?

Comment: Not really, you wouldn't need to deal with passwords, you would just assume that if the user has reached the app, they have the required access to the data

Comment: How can I explain this, the front of the app can display data world wide, but the back of it is secure by default, don't create methods for changing the back of the app (script, data etc.) by the app itself

Comment: Hattie35, almost every time I've seen user-managed passwords, there is some flaw in the implementation that results in a valid user being denied, an invalid user gaining access, or *just as much*, an invalid user walking away with a whole lot of internal data. It's not that there are any intentional shortcuts, it's that good security is really hard to do thoroughly, so we should instead rely on well-tested libraries or interfaces instead. Additionally, as @Bruno said, do it once: in the server, not in the app. (Though per-app perms are only slightly different.)

Comment: Given that ... comparing the *hash* of a password against a stored *hash* is certainly better than storing the password itself. This assumes that the hashing *always* happens, and always happens in the server (and not in client-visible code such as javascript, as that could allow spoofing).

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of your comments! I will consider all of these things as I work on my app.

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track. My advice is to use a package to handle your hashing/encryption, and encrypt your data too.

The approach would be:

1. User enters password into a text box (this is the private key)
2. Compare the private key to the public key stored in your app
3. If they match, decrypt your data / decrypt your database connection string

This provides a pretty good level of security, good enough for your company's dashboard, but not good enough for medical records.

Always assume that people can view the code and data behind a shiny app. This includes manually running database queries if there is no password or the password is stored in the app.

Below is minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(sodium)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    passwordInput("txt_password", "Enter Password"),
    
    actionButton("btn_action", "Submit")
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    #Load encrypted data
    data_encrypted <- readRDS("data_encrypted.rds")
    
    #Create a reactive dataframe to store the unencyrpted data
    reactives <- reactiveValues(data_unencrypted = NULL)
    
    #Public key (its okay to hardcode it here, public keys are designed for sharing)
    key_public <- "e5 c2 cb 08 27 41 26 1a 06 ad 9f 6a c9 29 ad 37 f0 66 f1 cd b7 f7 1e 24 e9 8b 26 8e 81 b6 68 16"
    
    #Observe submit button (runs once when submit button is clicked)
    observeEvent(input$btn_action, {
        
        #Private key
        key_private <- sha256(charToRaw(input$txt_password))

        #Check if private key provided is correct
        if(paste(pubkey(key_private), collapse = " ") == key_public) {
            
            showNotification("Correct password")
            
            #Unencrypt data and make it available elsewhere
            reactives$data_unencrypted <- unserialize(simple_decrypt(data_encrypted, key_private))
            
            #Print data to the console, so we can check it worked
            print(reactives$data_unencrypted )
            
        } else {
            
            showNotification("Incorrect password")
            
        }
        
    })
    
    #Remove all data when session ends
    cancel.onSessionEnded <- session$onSessionEnded(function() {
        rm(list = ls())
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The below code shows how you would encrypt your data before uploading your app:

```
library(sodium)

#Your password
mysupersecretpassword <- "abc"

#Your data
data_unencrypted <- data.frame(id = seq(1:10))

#Private key
key_private <- sha256(charToRaw(mysupersecretpassword))
paste("Private Key:", paste(key_private, collapse = " "))

#Public key
key_public  <- pubkey(key_private)
paste("Public Key:", paste(key_public, collapse = " "))

#Encrypt data
data_encrypted <- simple_encrypt(serialize(data_unencrypted, NULL), key_public)

#Save data
saveRDS(data_encrypted, "data_encrypted.rds")

#Cleanup
rm(list=ls())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Ash!